# Wrapper class in C for byte like java Byte,Integer,String,Double?

Tags: java, c

In Java Byte wrapper classes is there like

```
byte-Byte
int-Integer
float-Float etc
```

i want to use wrapper classes in c so anyone let 
me know how to use wrapper classes in c and how to write this in c??

JAVA:

```
Byte arr= 0x03;
```

Comment: in C there is no classes at all...

Comment: Perhaps you'd just tell us what functionality you want?

Comment: @FelicePollano Are you saying C has no class? How terribly rude :-)

Comment: Might be a JNI question.

Comment: You can't really, as C doesn't have any support to create new types like in Java or C++.

Comment: It has support to create new types, just not new classes. C structs are basically just a dumb collection of data.

Answer (score 2):

In C there are no classes at all. You could create a struct with a char member but I'm not really sure why you'd want to do that.

In C++, you could create a wrapper class. You just need to define implicit conversions to and from char to simulate autoboxing, as well as whatever methods you think the wrapper class should have.

Also, the equivalent of the Java 'byte' type in C and C++ is `signed char`.

Comment: That's just because *everything* is signed in Java.

Comment: @Bo, actually, chars are unsigned.

Answer (score 1):

In C you write `char arr = 0x03;`. There are no "wrapppers" or "boxing" for POD types. And you don't really need them.

Comment: for this code byte[] arr1=new byte[]{0x01}; i have written char arr1[]={0x01}; so for Byte there's no wrapper class in c so i can write like this char arr = 0x03; which is equivalent to Byte arr= 0x03; right?? thank you

Comment: @poppy: Yes, you can. That is, if you have a single byte. If you write `byte [] arr1...` in Java, that is called an array, and in C it could be either `char *array` or `char array[]`.

Comment: then In C what's the equivalent for java Integer,Short,Float wrapper class??

Comment: @poppy: See "Simple Java Data" here — http://www.d.umn.edu/~gshute/java/c2java.html